# Image Url Issue at client machine in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, deployment, path

i deployed a web application in which i saved images in folder name uploads and save its path in database

so the path in data base is looking as

```
"~\uploads\images.jpg"
```

and when i call it for view at run time as

```
 EmpImage.ImageUrl = dt.Rows[0]["Pic"].ToString();
```

where `EmpImage` is asp image control which get path at run time

and front end of `EmpImage` is

```
<asp:Image ID="EmpImage" runat="server" />
```

Image displayed here at my developing machine very fine but after publish i cannot see image that i saved

in browser when I `inspect element` i got `image url` as

```
images.jpg //only image name not complete path
```

and when i edit from browser in `inspect element` window to

```
//uploads//images.jpg
```

then image displayed,

if this was at front end side issue i can add this in `image url` manually but i gave path at run time in code behind

so i need this image to visible perfectly as this was in my PC. 
please suggest me what to do?

Comment: try printing 'dt.Rows[0]["Pic"].ToString();' from code behind and check what you are getting from database.

Comment: Store the path in the database as `/path/to/your/image.jpg`